# Terminate program and show error dialog on fatal exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

In a situation where a fatal exception occurs, it can be assumed that the program is no longer in a safe state to run and should be terminated as soon as possible. However, I would like to inform the user what fatal error has occurred without requiring them to go searching through log files. Is the best solution to terminate all other executing `Thread`s, only leaving the current thread alive for calling up a `JDialog`?

This was my attempt at the solution:

```
public void killAlienThreads() {
    Thread[] threads;

    while ((threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().toArray(new Thread[0])).length != 1) {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            if (thread != Thread.currentThread())
                thread.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

After this method is called, the current thread goes on to alert the user of the issue, and then close off the program once the remaining dialog is disposed.

There are many issues with this code. For one, new threads could be created while attempting to shut down all of them, this requires a loop that only breaks when it knows only the current thread is left. Also, as Eclipse warns me, `Thread.stop()` is deprecated, however `Thread.interrupt()` is not guaranteed to immediately stop a thread. Regardless, instead of terminating all other threads, this method simply gives me a barrage of `InterruptedException`s.

So, how can a program in an "unsafe state" be safely terminated while still allowing for an error dialog to inform the user?

**EDIT:**

Let me explain a couple things to make my question more clear. When I say "fatal exception" I mean a checked `Exception` (not an `Error`) that my program has caught and does not know how to deal with. When one of these errors occurs it can be assumed that the program is no longer in a functional state (or it is "unsafe") and should be terminated as soon as possible. However, waiting for the user to click the "OK" button on an error dialog can take an indefinite amount of time. So, I wish to terminate the program immediately when a "fatal exception occurs" without having to wait for the user to acknowledge the error dialog and close it.

Comment: "unsafe state" and "safely terminated" don't really make sense in the same phrase... I think it *is* possible (Windows did it with the old BSoDs), but I'm not sure that it'd be possible to do so in the JVM, since code you write generally doesn't run at the right level to deal with JVM errors.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you are looking for code review, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you are wondering how the JVM works, this is the place. If you want to debate how the JVM *should* behave then I suggest this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @user3580294 I've updated the question with a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While throwing a proper exception generally leave a lot of objects in a valid state, calling an unsafe method like `Thead.stop()` can completely corrupt important state and cause even more bad side effects.

The safest way is to let the main process die as quickly as possible and use another daemon process to report the error.

If you have to do it from within the JVM, you'll probably have to look at debugging or instrumentation APIs as it is not possible to interrupt a thread that does not call interruptable methods.

Comment: Could you provide an example of using a daemon process to report the error?